# How to get GET params from express with typescript in node.js?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, eslint

Im using node.js + express + typescript, and I want to get GET params. I have this so far

```
app.get('/top_games', (req, res) => {
    const page = req.route.page;
    const offset = req.route.offset;
    const game_data = DAO_GAME.GetTopGuilds(100, 0);
    res.send({
        total : game_data[0],
        data : game_data[1]
    });
});
```

but the eslint complains for

```
    const page = req.route.page;
    const offset = req.route.offset;
```

saying

```
Unsafe assignment of an any value.eslint@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-assignment
Unsafe member access .page on an any value.eslint@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-member-access
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: What does req.params give you? app.get('/user/:id', function (req, res) {
  res.send('user ' + req.params.id)
})

Comment: `req.params` gets me `{}`, the data is in `req.query`

Comment: https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.query

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it, I had to do

```
const page = parseInt(req.query.page as string, 10);
const page_size = parseInt(req.query.page_size as string, 10);
```

Answer (score 1):

As of `@types/express@4.17.2`, the [`Request` type uses generics](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/express/index.d.ts#L108). We can use this to type the parsed query parameters ourselves:

```js
import { Request } from 'express';

type QueryParams = {
    page: string;
    page_size: string;
};

app.get('/top_games', (req: Request<{}, {}, {}, QueryParams>, res) => {
    const page = parseInt(req.route.page, 10);
    const offset = parseInt(req.route.offset, 10);

    // ...
});
```

Comment: Thank you for answering this, I've just spent the last few days trying to figure this out and this is exactly what I was looking for